# Permission Denied, Laravel and Monolog -

Tags: laravel, monolog

Error in exception handler:

> The stream or file "/home/wwwroot/default/tor_service/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/wwwroot/default/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:84

Anyone knows how to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: This says that you do not have the permission to write to the file `/home/wwwroot/default/tor_service/app/storage/logs/laravel.log`, make sure that you can create a file and edit its content in the above path.

Comment: Can you explain a little more in detail please?

Comment: You should exec the `touch /home/wwwroot/default/tor_service/app/storage/logs/laravel.log` in your console under the user that your web server is running to see if there is any errors.

Answer (score -2):

Storage folder should be writable by your web server.

You can change the owner of the `storage` directory to `www-data`

```
chown -R www-data:www-data storage
```

Comment: **Warning:** Before deciding to defeat the security provided by having file permissions differentiated by user and operational requirements, think carefully about the risk you're taking. See [_Why shouldn't /var/www have chmod 777?_](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20105)